# Why does Microsoft lock users from signing-in to their apps based on their geographic locations?

Tags: microsoft-account, location-services, geolocation

Every time I try to sign in Microsoft Groove or Movies and TV, I get this message."Can't sign in. Sorry, signing-in is not supported in your area at this time"

Cortana is locked. Groove signing-in is locked. Movies and TV signing-in is locked. All these services closed on me because of my geographic location. What's wrong with Microsoft? Why do they do that? What do they gain from blocking their users from signing-in in certain regions?

[image: Error message 0xc00d1388]

Comment: That's question is for your government

Comment: those services aren't available in some regions, for eg: i too can't sign in because the service is unavailable in India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons for this - legal, business or political.

1. TV shows and movies might not be licensed for purchase in your country
2. Cortana might not speak/understand the language of your country
3. Microsoft can't provide customer support in local language (no local support center, personnel not trained for specific product, etc.)

You should not take things like that personal :) Because they are not